# Find char index where contains() found sequence

Tags: java, string

```
    if(input.contains("Angle ")) {
        input.charAt(?);
    }
```

So, basically, how would you find the char directly after "Angle "? In absolute simplest terms, how do you find the indexes in which "Angle " was found?

Comment: Have you searched for how to find the indices of substrings in Java? This is a foundational string operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method both to find out that the input contains the string, and where its index is:

```
int pos = input.indexOf("Angle ");
if (pos >= 0) {
    ... // Substring is found at index pos
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the indexOf() method?

From java doc...

> Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the
>   specified substring. The integer returned is the smallest value k such
>   that:  this.startsWith(str, k)   is true.

Then since you know the length of the string, you could add that to the input to find the char directly after "Angle ".

Comment: Don't forget to check the return of `indexOf()` first; it is a potentially easy mistake to blindly add `"Angle ".length()` to `-1` and come up with an erroneous result.

Answer (score 0):

To find the word following "Angle ", you could use regex:

```
String next = str.replaceAll(".*Angle (\\w+).*", "$1");
```

Then you don't have to sully yourself with indexes, iteration and lots of code.

Answer (score 0):

As [others have stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22586411/616460), you may use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) to find the location of the substring. If you have more than one occurrence of the substring and you want to find all of them, you can use [the version of `indexOf` that takes a starting position](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to continue the search after the current occurrence, e.g. to find all occurrences of `needle` in `haystack`:

```
int index = 0;

while ((index = haystack.indexOf(needle, index)) != -1) {
    System.out.println("Found substring at " + index);
    index += needle.length();
}
```

Note, by the way, that `.contains(needle)` is essentially the same as `.indexOf(needle) > -1` (in fact, that is [precisely how `contains()` is implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)).